# VB check for Null Reference when passing ByRef

Tags: vb.net, null, pass-by-reference

I have a function that accepts a String by reference:

```
Function Foo(ByRef input As String)
```

If I call it like this:

```
Foo(Nothing)
```

I want it to do something different than if I call it like this:

```
Dim myString As String = Nothing
Foo(myString)
```

Is it possible to detect this difference in the way the method is called in VB .NET?

**Edit**

To clarify *why* the heck I would want to do this, I have two methods:

```
Function Foo()
  Foo(Nothing)
End Function

Function Foo(ByRef input As String)
  'wicked awesome logic here,  hopefully
End Function
```

All the logic is in the second overload, but I want to perform a different branch of logic if `Nothing` was passed into the function than if a variable *containing* `Nothing` was passed in.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because I have an overload of a function, but the overload calls to the other function overload and passes Nothing for that parameter.

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, but in that case, you shouldn't care which way this was created.  The function should just run knowing that it's receiving `Nothing` as input.

Comment: @Brandon: If you truly need different behavior when your overload is called, you should put that in the overloaded function.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify why I would want to do this.

Comment: @Brandon - your last sentence is what I was questioning.  WHY do you care whether Nothing was passed in vs. a variable containing nothing?

Comment: @Brandon: That being said, my answer still stands - this isn't possible.  You're passing a copy of a string reference into the method - internally, it's exactly the same either way according to the CLR.

Comment: So a null reference is the same thing as a reference to a null value?

Comment: @Brandon: Yes.  In both cases, it's an instance of a reference with a value of "0", basically, saying it's pointing to Nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  In either case, the method "sees" a reference to a string (`input`) which is pointing to nothing.

From the method's point of view, these are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Null Reference check either:

1) prior to calling the function

```
If myString IsNot Nothing Then 
     Foo(myString)
End If
```

2) or inside the function

```
Function Foo(ByRef input As String)
    If input Is Nothing Then
        Rem Input is null
    Else
        Rem body of function
    End If
End Function
```